# How to link a 3rd party library in linux for qml project

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

How do i link a 3rd party library in Qt Creator for a Qt Quick UI application.
I have library files built in linux(.so)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your should create "Qt Quick Application *" project and .pro file should look like:

```
QT += core quick gui network
TEMPLATE = app
HEADERS += some .h files
SOURCES += some .cpp files
INCLUDEPATH += ../include
OTHER_FILES += *.qml #or path to qml files
LIBS += -lprotobuf  # list of Libs, which you wish
```

Comment: u wish to create a Qt Quick UI,not Qt Quick Application.Is it possible?

Comment: also if possible to do it via Qt Quick Application,then how do i include my qml files?

Comment: qml files can be included as OTHER_FILES in .pro file.
Also,possible to add them via QtCreator in project menu -> "Add New" and selected Qt|QML file.

In project tree these files are defined as "QML".